# What is this file format called

Tags: json, file-format

I need to parse a file which is in the following format:

```
"General"
{
"Description" = "Some Text"
"Version" = "4"
"ProjType" = "1"
}
"Configurations"
{
    "Mice"
    {
    "BuildOutputs" = "BuildProject"
    "OutputFile" = "output.txt"
    }
    "Men"
    {
    "BuildOutputs" = "BuildProject"
    "ChangedSinceLastBuilt" = "True"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what file format this is? If it's well known then there could be already made libraries to help parse it. It appears to be similar to JSON but instead of colons it uses equals sign and instead of commas it forcefully uses a new line.

Comment: What language do you need to parse it in?

Comment: Couldn't you just read the content of the file, replace `=` with `:` and the newlines with `,`?

Comment: Thats dependant on whether or not libraries already exist but would be helpful in to be in Python, ANT, NANT or Java

Comment: @krister-andersson ah you mean convert it to JSON then use a ready made library to parse it, good idea.

Comment: @krister-andersson add your comment as an answer and I will mark it correct if no one is able to give a name for the file format.

Comment: @GraemeKidd - Done=) What is the extension of the file you're trying to parse?

Comment: I also came a cross a string formatted like that. Parsing works fine (when I replace the chars like mentioned), but I also wonder what format that is, cause it seems 'quite' popular. In my case I got it from a command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply read in the entire file and then convert `=` to `:` and each line break with `,` - then you could parse it with an existing json library. Perhaps you would have to insert a `;` at the end of the data.

Comment: Yeah I might need to add a root level of `{` `}` brackets as well but it seems to be the simplest option if this turns out to a propriety file format.