# what is the format of this data? is it a custom format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataformat

I get this data as an ajax response:

```
{
    "idArray" = (
        "99516",
        "99518",
        "97344",
        "97345",
        "98425"
    );
    "frame" = {
        "size" = {
            "width" = "8";
            "height" = "8";
        };
        "origin" = {
            "x" = "244";
            "y" = "345";
        };
    };
},
```

This is just a portion of the Data, but it continues in the same format.
I don't have access to the source of the files that generate this data.

Is this a known format or something custom?

Comment: @DLeh — It is not JSON. Why would you expect tags added by someone who doesn't know what data format something is in to include the tag for the right data format?

Comment: That's improper JSON DLeh...The equal sign

Comment: @Mechkov — There are at least three other non-JSON features in the data format.

Comment: You can replace "()" with "[]" and "=" with ":" and you will get a JSON object

Comment: I would also like to know the name of this data format unless it's arbitrary, in which case you should be upset at them for not using JSON or something similar.

Comment: @Ragnar Not quite, you'd still need to remove the semicolons.

Comment: It looks to me like someone tried to create a JSON object but has no idea what he or she is doing.

Comment: similar unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330761/what-is-this-file-format-called

Comment: Six upvotes? Really?

Comment: This almost looks like a groovy configuration file. `test {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }` See http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since people tend to throw regular expressions at everything, even things that can not be parsed with regular expressions (ie. non-regular languages): I've written a proof-of-concept parser for this data format:

```
$input = '{
    "idArray" = (
        "99516",
        "99518",
        "97344",
        "97345",
        "98425"
    );
    "frame" = {
        "size" = {
            "width" = "8";
            "height" = "8";
        };
        "origin" = {
            "x" = "244";
            "y" = "345";
        };
    };
}';

echo json_encode(parse($input));

function parse($input) {
    $tokens = tokenize($input);
    $index = 0;
    $result = parse_value($tokens, $index);
    if ($result[1] !== count($tokens)) {
        throw new Exception("parsing stopped at token " . $result[1] . " but there is more input");
    }
    return $result[0][1];
}

function tokenize($input) {
    $tokens = array();
    $length = strlen($input);
    $pos = 0;
    while($pos < $length) {
        list($token, $pos) = find_token($input, $pos);
        $tokens[] = $token;
    }
    return $tokens;
}

function find_token($input, $pos) {
    $static_tokens = array("=", "{", "}", "(", ")", ";", ",");
    while(preg_match("/\s/mis", substr($input, $pos, 1))) { // eat whitespace
        $pos += 1;
    }
    foreach ($static_tokens as $static_token) {
        if (substr($input, $pos, strlen($static_token)) === $static_token) {
            return array($static_token, $pos + strlen($static_token));
        }
    }
    if (substr($input, $pos, 1) === '"') {
        $length = strlen($input);
        $token_length = 1;
        while ($pos + $token_length < $length) {
            if (substr($input, $pos + $token_length, 1) === '"') {
                return array(array("value", substr($input, $pos + 1, $token_length - 1)), $pos + $token_length + 1);
            }
            $token_length += 1;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("invalid input at " . $pos . ": `" . substr($input, $pos - 10, 20) . "`");
}

// value is either an object {}, an array (), or a literal ""
function parse_value($tokens, $index) {
    if ($tokens[$index] === "{") {  // object: a list of key-value pairs, glued together by ";"
        $return_value = array();
        $index += 1;
        while ($tokens[$index] !== "}") {
            list($key, $value, $index) = parse_key_value($tokens, $index);
            $return_value[$key] = $value[1];
            if ($tokens[$index] !== ";") {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected: " . print_r($tokens[$index], true));
            }
            $index += 1;
        }
        return array(array("object", $return_value), $index + 1);
    }
    if ($tokens[$index] === "(") {  // array: a list of values, glued together by ",", the last "," is optional
        $return_value = array();
        $index += 1;
        while ($tokens[$index] !== ")") {
            list($value, $index) = parse_value($tokens, $index);
            $return_value[] = $value[1];
            if ($tokens[$index] === ",") {  // last, is optional
                $index += 1;
            } else {
                if ($tokens[$index] !== ")") {
                    throw new Exception("Unexpected: " . print_r($tokens[$index], true));
                }
                return array(array("array", $return_value), $index + 1);
            }
        }
        return array(array("array", $return_value), $index + 1);
    }
    if ($tokens[$index][0] === "value") {
        return array(array("string", $tokens[$index][1]), $index + 1);
    }
    throw new Exception("Unexpected: " . print_r($tokens[$index], true));
}

// find a key (string) followed by '=' followed by a value (any value)
function parse_key_value($tokens, $index) {
    list($key, $index) = parse_value($tokens, $index);
    if ($key[0] !== "string") { // key must be a string
        throw new Exception("Unexpected: " . print_r($key, true));
    }
    if ($tokens[$index] !== "=" ) {
        throw new Exception("'=' expected");
    }
    $index += 1;
    list($value, $index) = parse_value($tokens, $index);
    return array($key[1], $value, $index);
}
```

The output is:

```
{"idArray":["99516","99518","97344","97345","98425"],"frame":{"size":{"width":"8","height":"8"},"origin":{"x":"244","y":"345"}}}
```

Notes

- the original input has a trailing `,`. I've removed that character. It will throw an error (more input) if you put it back.
- This parser is naive in the sense that it tokenizes all input before it starts parsing. This is not good for large input.
- I've not added escape detection for strings in the tokenizer. Like: `"foo\"bar"`.

This was a fun exercise. If you have any questions let me know.

Edit: I see this is a JavaScript question. Porting the PHP to JavaScript shouldn't be too hard. The `list($foo, $bar) = func()` is equivalent to: `var res = func(); var foo = res[0]; var bar = res[1];`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function with the response text as a parameter:

```
function getJsonData(str){
    str = str.replace(/,/g, '')         //remove ,
             .replace(/\(/g, '[')       //replace (
             .replace(/\[/g)', ']')     //replace )
             .replace(/;/g, ',')        //replace ; 
             .replace(/=/g, ':');       //replace :
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

This is an edit made by @SamSal

```
function getJsonData(str){
    str = str.replace(/\(/g, '[')       //replace (
         .replace(/\)/g, ']')       //replace )
         .replace(/;\n\s+}/g, '}')  //replace ;} with }
         .replace(/;/g, ',')        //replace remaining ; with ,  
         .replace(/=/g, ':');       //replace :
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous. If your data contains any of these characters you're going to get data corruption. This data format seems parseable.

Comment: Yes, but in this case there are only numbers in all field, there is no text

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a known format or something custom?

It is a custom format, that looks a *little* bit like [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) without actually being JSON.